# In C#, how can I format integers with zero-padding without making negative values longer?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm working in C# .Net 5.0, Visual Studio. I'm formatting integers to have zero-padding like so

```
$"{-1:d04}"
$"{1:d04}"
```

Formatting positive and negative numbers give different lengths of the resulting strings

```
-0001
0001
```

I need my numbers to be the *same length* (i.e. the result in this example should be the strings `"-001"` and `"0001"`), does there exist any formatting pattern to achieve this?

Comment: `x < 0 ? $"{x:d03}" : $"{x:d04}"`?

Comment: I don't want to display the values, I'm doing this as a technique for sorting strings. I format strings against different parameters by prefixing a fixed length value at the front. I then cut away the parameter when I print the string

Comment: I'm also forming chains like this `$"{r6[0]:d04}{r6[1]:d04}{r6[2]:d04}{r6[3]:d04}";` so if I have to use conditional operators it will grow a lot (i.e. ideally looking for a formatting pattern)

Comment: I'm not getting why you are trying to sort strings by formatting numbers. Why not use an `IComparer`?

Comment: I just have a lot of parameters to sort strings against and I only need a one-time result (i.e. the code quality is not important) It was going really well as long as all the params where positive ..

Comment: I see, so the actual format isn't very important as long as they're the same length? See my edit.

Comment: You'll need to check that the comparison really works for negative numbers - if you're performing a simple string comparison, it's hard to see how you'd get "1" < "2" but "-1" > "-2" (both of which you want).

Comment: @Jon Skeet excellent point but for my application I'm actually tolerant towards the sorting not being perfect! It's suffcient for me that the same numbers are next to each other. However using different lengths ints is not acceptable because it will cut away characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use the [`;` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--section-separator) to provide two formats for non-negative and negative numbers.

```
int x = 1;
Console.WriteLine($"{x:0000;-000}"); // "0001"
x = -1;
Console.WriteLine($"{x:0000;-000}"); // "-001"
```

`0000` for positive numbers, `-000` for negative numbers.

This does mean that you no longer use the standard format specifier `D`, which automatically uses the [`NegativeSign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign?view=net-5.0) from the current `NumberFormatInfo`. You'd have to hardcode the negative sign in. This may or may not be a problem depending on what you are doing.

Edit:

Apparently this is for sorting strings. If the format doesn't have to be exactly "0001" and "-001", and just has to be the same length, then I suggest:

```
int x = 1;
Console.WriteLine($"{x,5:d04}"); // " 0001" (note the leading space)
x = -1;
Console.WriteLine($"{x,5:d04}"); // "-0001"
```

Comment: many thanks for the edit, yes that's even better.  It has also occurred to me that another way to do this is to bring them out of negative range by adding an offset!